# Designing partition key to ensure data of particular type goes to same shard in Kinesis

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I am new to AWS Kinesis data stream. In my use case, I would like to set up a Kinesis data stream with 2 shards, where one shard I would like to put the data related to say, Student, and in another shard, I would like to put the data related to Teacher.

Here, my question how can I design a partition key to ensure that data related to Student and Teacher don't land up in the same shard in the Kinesis data stream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each shard will be given **fixed range of partition keys**. You can get this range using [describe-stream](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/kinesis/describe-stream.html).

For example, for the first shard:

```
                "HashKeyRange": {
                    "StartingHashKey": "0",
                    "EndingHashKey": "113427455640312821154458202477256070484"
                },
```

Thus before you start streaming, you can programmatically check the ranges and choose key from the respective ranges.

Having this you can use [ExplicitHashKey](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecordsRequestEntry.html#Streams-Type-PutRecordsRequestEntry-ExplicitHashKey) when you `PutRecords` to **explicitly specify** which shard they should go.

Comment: Note that using explicitHashKey might break the program if later you decide to scale.